# how to change primary key from null to not null in mysql?

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have the following table

```
create table ooor (
 id int(10) PRIMARY KEY,
 name varcha(20),
 city varchar(20) UNIQUE KEY
                  );
```

and its primary key value shown is null and i want its value to change to not null without deleting table.
so , how can i do it ??

from

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| city  | varchar(20) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

to

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int         | NO   | PRI | NOT NULL|       |
| name  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| city  | varchar(20) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

note: i know its the column which has primary key value is not null by default , i want to change its wriiten value (NULL to NOT NULL).

Comment: Have you tried `ALTER TABLE ooor MODIFY COLUMN id INT(11) NOT NULL;` ?

Comment: `NULL` is a value, `NOT NULL` is an expression, can it be a default value?

Comment: a pk field CANT!!! be NULL. That is one of the difference between PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE INDEX. THE UNIQUE INDEX can hold NULLs

Comment: What do you mean you want to change it's written value? Null isn't blank. It's devoid of all value. Are you saying you want to change the values to an empty string?

Comment: 'PRIMARY KEY

A unique index where all key columns must be defined as NOT NULL. If they are not explicitly declared as NOT NULL, MySQL declares them so implicitly (and silently)' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html - annoying but there you are..

Comment: @Martin , YES sir i tried and receive an error ::--- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL' at line 1

Comment: @ProGu sir, i don't understand , please elaborate

Comment: @BerndBuffen sir, i know that . so how to change its appearence from NULL to NOT NULL?

Comment: @ghajini - first you must drop the primary key. Then you can change the structure like ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN ... and the add a new PRIMARY KEY

Comment: @BerndBuffen yes sir , i do it but it cant change its appearence as in my question

Comment: @ghajini-  **ALTER TABLE `ooor` DROP PRIMARY KEY;** to DELETE and :
**ALTER TABLE `ooor` ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);** TO ADD the PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Heidi Sql to actually do what you just said, this was the command executed to accomplish what you're asking. This doesn't require that you remake the table or anything. It simply changed the table where it is.

```
ALTER TABLE `ooor`
CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(50) NOT NULL
```

Comment: yes sir , i got it ,we cant change its appearence ever after creating new table with taking NOT NULL as @P.Salmon mentioned it in comment